# C# Access to form components from class

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have method which contains in Form1 class

```
 public void ExecuteMessageOperations(MSMQMessage MSMQ)
    {
        switch (MSMQ.MesType)
        {
            case "01": { label1.Text = MSMQ.MesContent; MessageBox.Show(MSMQ.MesContent); button1.Text = MSMQ.MesContent; };
                break;
            case "02":
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Data", "Data");
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(MSMQ.MesContent);

                };
                break;
            case "03":
                {
                    string[] separated = MSMQ.MesContent.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
                    try
                    {
                        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt16(separated[0]),
                            Convert.ToInt16(separated[1]), Convert.ToInt16(separated[2]),
                            Convert.ToInt16(separated[2]));
                        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(XMLConfigs.GetBrushColor());
                        Graphics Grph = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
                        Grph.FillEllipse(brush, rect);

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong parameters");
                    };
                };
                break;
        }
```

And class which called MSMQMessageThread and it contains out of the Form1. This class have method

```
public void PerformOperations()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Form1 f = new Form1();
                f.ExecuteMessageOperations(MSMQMessage.ReceiveMessage(@".\private$\TestQueue"));
            }
            catch (System.Messaging.MessageQueueException) { }
        }
    }
```

Code compiles normally but method ExecuteMessageOperations do nothing. Where is the mistake and how can i access the Form1 components in method ExecuteMessageOperations ?
P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: Have you tried to remove `catch (System.Messaging.MessageQueueException) { }` and not to swallow exception silently? Probably your `MSMQMessage.ReceiveMessage` throws exception and you ignore it in empty catch block

Comment: No it's working properly. That try catch standing there for catch exception of timeout.
 var message = (MSMQMessage)mq.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0),
            MessageQueueTransactionType.Single).Body;

Comment: so ok, what do you mean by `do nothing`? It's not being called at all or it doesn't perform any work, so there is no observable side effect? Could you at least try to help us solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Method is working but the code below(which contains in method ExecuteMessageOperations) do nothing.
label1.Text = MSMQ.MesContent;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Data", "Data");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(MSMQ.MesContent);
Graphics Grph = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
Grph.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
Probably there is something with access to components of my Form1

Comment: Nowhere in this code do I see anything related to form visability, is it possible that this code is in fact working just fine, but you can't see it because you never show the form or any of its components?

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint where your switch statement and 'step over'. Let us know if it is actually calling the method in the first place.

Comment: Yes it's calling method. 

MessageBox.Show(MSMQ.MesContent); 

This code was written for test and it's working for the each time when message arrives